# How to push success/fail screen after processing open launcher other app in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I would like to make an action after processing completed from other app in flutter.

Example: I have a flutter app which open googlemap app by url_launcher library, then user press on back then it will move back to flutter app and in the point I wantto reload or push new screen. Is there any way can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After launching another app and then returning to your **Flutter** app, you might want to handle the outcome and navigate to the **success or fail** screen. To do this, you can utilize **Flutter's navigation system** and the `didPop` method from the `RouteObserver` class.

*Here's how you can achieve this:*

**Set Up Route Observers:**

You need to set up a `RouteObserver` to observe the navigation in your **Flutter** app. You can create a custom `RouteObserver` for this purpose.

```
class MyAppRouteObserver extends RouteObserver<PageRoute<dynamic>> {
  static final MyAppRouteObserver _instance = MyAppRouteObserver._();

  factory MyAppRouteObserver() => _instance;

  MyAppRouteObserver._();

  void didPop(Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic>? previousRoute) {
    super.didPop(route, previousRoute);

    // Check if the previously visited route was the launched app
    if (previousRoute is AppLaunchRoute) {
      // Here, you can handle the outcome (success or failure)
      bool processingSuccess = true; // Replace with your logic

      if (processingSuccess) {
        navigatorKey.currentState?.push(SuccessScreen.route());
      } else {
        navigatorKey.currentState?.push(FailScreen.route());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Handle Route Changes:**

When you launch another app using **platform-specific** code (e.g., opening a web browser), you can add a route representing the launched app and tell your custom `RouteObserver` when this **route** is pushed.

> Inside your main.dart

```
final MyAppRouteObserver routeObserver = MyAppRouteObserver();

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
      navigatorObservers: [routeObserver], // Add the route observer
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('My App')),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            // Launch another app (e.g., a web browser)
            await launchURL('https://example.com');

            // Push a route representing the launched app
            navigatorKey.currentState?.push(AppLaunchRoute());

            // Handle the outcome in the RouteObserver
          },
          child: Text('Launch Another App'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Define Routes for Success and Fail Screens:**

You can define named routes for the **success** and **fail** screens using `MaterialPageRoute` or any other navigation method you prefer.

```
class SuccessScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Success')),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Processing was successful!'),
      ),
    );
  }

  static Route<dynamic> route() {
    return MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (_) => SuccessScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class FailScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Fail')),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Processing failed!'),
      );
  }

  static Route<dynamic> route() {
    return MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (_) => FailScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Mehran Ullah, it works!